# When to replace a battery jump-starter?

Tags: battery, jump-start, battery-drain

I have a battery jump-starter for many years (more than 5).  I wonder if I should replace it now.  How can I tell if it needs to be replaced?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is it you are using? Is it a jump box (completely self contained - rechargeable) or a battery charger which plugs into the wall?

Comment: It is called "Peak(TM) Battery Jump-Starter 450" Model No: PKC0AZ
  https://www.lanescarproducts.com/peak-450-amp-jump-starter-w-usb-12-v-power-source-pkc0az/?utm_source=googlepepla&utm_medium=adwords&id=293946777986&gclid=CjwKCAjw8_nXBRAiEiwAXWe2yVmhkinfAIsq_H9KUJnLQQk3DnWfXrWJ-D3pb_f0Hgou7TSch0XwWhoCR_wQAvD_BwE

Comment: Replace the whole thing or just its power source?

Comment: @Solar Mike -- I guess the whole thing -- the internal battery is not designed to be user replaceable.

Comment: Have you tried starting your car with it?

Comment: IME the internal batteries cannot be obtained for a price significantly less than the entire unit, probably due to economies of scale of containers of the things being made in China in 100,000 quantity, vs vs. the overhead of a low-volume "stock it, throw it in a box, deal with customer service, all in the US" parts operation. @Valorum that's hard to do if your car battery is actually good.

Comment: @Harper - Not really. Just disconnect the battery lead and start the car. The alternator should provide enough power to run the car, at least for long enough to check that the jump starter is turning over the ignition (or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would replace the whole thing. Not only because lead-acid gel cell batteries typically won't have a shelf life of more than 5 years, but also because today, a one-pound lithium ion jump starter can provide the required current and the 17 lb beast you have is needlessly heavy.

Your jump starter due to its weight almost certainly has gel cell lead-acid batteries (or probably just one). I had after 5 years of use a pair of gel-cells worn out in my UPS, which was nearly always connected to the mains, i.e. the batteries were continuously float-charged which supposedly should be more forgiving to the batteries than leaving them unused for many years (even though I did check the float charge voltage and adjusted it slightly down from 13.8 V to 13.65 V in the middle of the recommended 13.5V - 13.8V range for room temperature).

Fortunately, the newer lithium ion cells should have a better calendar life and less self-discharge in addition to the major advantage, less weight.

Comment: For completeness, here's one which is slightly more expensive, has slightly less current providing capacity, but will weigh much less than a pound in comparison to 17 pounds: https://www.omegamechanix.nl/en/workshop/jumpstarters/omega-mechanix-ijs11000-/